# Duplicate symbols issue with 2 third party libraries in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, compiler-construction, static-libraries

I'm trying to compile a project that depends on 2 third party static libraries.

The issue is that both third parties have included the same set of "utility" classes in their static library distribution, meaning that I am getting dozens of duplicate symbol errors when both are added to my project.

Is there a way for me to force the project to compile and/or ignore one of the duplicate symbols somehow?

I found a similar question with answer here [two static libraries with duplicate symbols in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377420/two-static-libraries-with-duplicate-symbols-in-xcode) but I am interested to see if there is a compiler flag that might do the trick (please note that in this case I am assuming that both symbols represent the same object).

Thanks
Rog

Comment: @Rog did you find any cleaner solution

Comment: Nope sorry I managed to get a version of one of the library without the duplicate symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Try merge them into one file via libtool (libtool -o merged.a file1.a file2.a) or check [How can I avoid “duplicate symbol” errors in xcode with shared static libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300867/how-can-i-avoid-duplicate-symbol-errors-in-xcode-with-shared-static-libraries) or/and [Solving “Duplicate Symbol” Error When Setting Up GorillaLogic’s FoneMonkey 5](http://jojitsoriano.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/solving-duplicate-symbol-error-when-setting-up-gorillalogics-fonemonkey-5/)

Answer (score 0):

Just find the duplicate symbol file and rename one of the library corresponding files. Be aware that you should check all compiled sources of the project that you are renaming. Xcode won't change the references automatically.